# How do I calculate conversion rate using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, metrics

I have created a goal in Google Analytics that is met when the user completes the sign up process. The page that they end up at is

```
http://my_url.com/?just_signed_up=true
```

In order to calculate my conversation rate, I need to do this calculation:

```
goal (sign ups) / new visitors
```

I know that in order to use new visitor numbers, I can either set up a profile with a new visitor filter or just apply a new user advanced segment on my normal profile.

My problem is that the Google Analytics tracking code is on every page in my site, including my landing page. The sign up process goes like this:

```
Landing page -> Sign up form -> http://my_url.com/?just_signed_up=true
```

When the user ends up at the URL above, am I correct in thinking that Google Analytics will no longer consider them a new user, as they would have the cookie from when they landed on the landing page at the start of the sign up process? If so, then there will never be a new visitor that meets the goal. How would I calculate my conversion rate in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A returning visitor is someone who starts an additional Google Analytics session while using your site. To start a new session they need to close their browser or stop using the site for a period of at least 30 minutes. Browsing around your site clicking links isn't considered stating a new session. This means that, in most cases, signups from new users will be from people (or at least browsers with a set of cookies) who have not visited your site before.